# What are widely-used, practical applications to come from the study #P problems?

Tags: complexity-theory, polynomial-time, counting

When, beyond theoretical exercises, do we care how many solutions we can find for something?

I had an analogous question for TMs before - why is it useful to study machines that can only deliver acceptance and rejection as output? Here, the answer (at least in a practical context) seems more clear - find a solution (e.g., a shortest path in a shortest path problem) is a matter of  poly-time reduction to yes/no answers. For #P problems, reduction is equally obvious, but not useful, since you're solving a problem at least as hard.

Comment: We don't have a strict policy for list questions, but there is a [general dislike](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/). Please note also [this](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/20) and [this](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/145/) discussion; you might want to improve your question as to avoid the problems explained there. If you are not sure how to improve your question maybe we can help you in [chat]?

Comment: Yes, now it's a list question. Above comment applies.